# How to delegate correct Action<Interface>?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, delegates, compiler-errors

I'm a beginner with C# and can't find any answer for this :

Im trying to delegate Actions with some interface parameter , but push through functions with objects that extend this interface (or class)

```
// some class extending interface
public class IntEvent : IFace{}
public class MoveEvent : IFace{}

// function i like to use to verify Action
static void setAction(Action<IFace> evt) {
    // evt ...
}
// function to delegate as Action
static void evtCheck(IntEvent evt) {
    // some func
}
static void evtMove(MoveEvent evt) {
    // some func
}
// class {
//  call method inside class and delegate this function :
setAction(evtCheck);
setAction(evtMove);
```

I'm receiving an error that "`evtCheck(IntEvent)` cannot be converted to `Action<IFace>`" , even if `IntEvent` extends the `IFace` interface .

How should I solve this ? Maybe I have to use Func or Delegate ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do - you're expecting covariance, but [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) is *contravariant* on its only type-parameter.

You can't do a method-group conversion from `evtCheck` to `Action<IFace>` because `evtCheck` needs a *more specific* type (`IntEvent`) as its argument than the more general `IFace` type that an `Action<IFace>` instance expects. If such a conversion were allowed, what would you expect to happen if the delegate were executed with an argument that implements `IFace` but is not an `IntEvent`?

I think you should have another look at your design because it looks like there's a flaw there, but if you want, you can create a lambda to force a cast of the argument to the desired type and accept the possibility of an `InvalidCastException`:

```
setAction(iFace => evtCheck((IntEvent)iface));
```

More likely, you might want to make `evtCheck` accept a more general type or `setAction` to accept a more specific delegate.

Answer (score 5):

`Action<T>` is contravariant in T, so methods taking an `Action<T>` will also accept `Action<U>` where T is derived from U.

Your `IntEvent` class, however, implements the `IFace` interface, which means that if the compiler accepted your `setAction()` call, it would be possible to call `evtCheck()` with an argument that is another `IFace`-derivative and not `IntEvent`, a runtime error and a clear violation of type safety.

Obligatory Eric Lippert reference: [Covariance and contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/)

EDIT: from your description it seems to me that what you really want is differentiation based on the method parameter's type, so e.g. you want a separate action for `IntEvent`, another one for (a hypothetical) `DoubleEvent` etc. If this is the case, you are actually after double virtual dispatch, which is not directly supported in C#, but you can simulate it using the [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_%28design_pattern%29) design pattern.

Comment: Yeah , this is what im trying to do . Action functions always expect object that extend same interface or object . Ok , I'll look at visitor design pattern .